# Convergence of absolutely summable sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences, absolute-convergence

$I$ is some index set.

Let $l^1(I, \mathbb{R})$ denote the set of all sequences $a : I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sum_{i \in I} |a(i)| < +\infty$.

Let $a_n \in l^1(I, \mathbb{R})$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$\sum_{i \in I}|a_n(i) - a_{n+1}(i)| < 2^{-n}$

After some working, this leads to

$\sum_{i \in I} \sum_{n = 0}^\infty |a_n(i) - a_{n+1}(i)| = 2 < +\infty$.

I want to show from here that $\lim_n a_n(i) = a(i)$ exists for all $i \in I$.

where $a \in l^1(I, \mathbb{R})$

Comment: What is $a_{n+1}$? $a_n$ is a sequence with index set $I$ but what is $a_{n+1}$? Is it an arbitrary other sequence in $l^1(I,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: You need to prove that for each $i$, there exists a limit $a(i)\in\mathbf{R}$, and then you need to show that for those $a(i)$'s that $\sum_i |a(i)| <\infty$, correct? What have you worked on and where are you getting stuck?